# How do I move my Google Code Subversion repo to CollabNet

Tags: svn, google-code, collabnet

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to move my Subversion repository from Google Code to my CollabNet Subversion Edge server. I have read about making dump files, and migrating, and backing up and sync and just can't find the right answer. I think what's happening is that I don't know exactly what to type into Google. I'm just at a complete loss. I have been searching for about 3 hours now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtain a dump file of your repository from Google Code.  In Subversion Edge, create a new empty repository and then use the Load option to load the dump file that you obtained from Google Code.

If Google does not let you download a dump file, then you should be able to create a new empty repository in SVN Edge and then use the svnsync command line tool from any client to synch the repository from Google Code to your Subversion Edge repository.  To do this, you will just need to turn on the pre-revprop-change hook in the Subversion Edge repository.  The hook script can just be an empty file or have a single line of "exit 0".

Comment: ARG that means i was sooo close. The first bit i couldn't figure out and i tried for a long time (which was to make a dump file) I couldn't get that figured out though. So then i switched to the svnsync and it gave me the error about not having the hook thingy. I thought it said it had to be at google code so i gave up. but now that i think about it i accidently switched source and destination in my sync command, and it almost worked but said that the revisions was more in destination than in source.. which means it had that file hook thingy. I will try that tomorrow when i get to work. thanks

Comment: C:\>svnsync init http://***********/svn/Aspects --sync-usernam
e admin --sync-password ********* https://adli.googlecode.com/svn --source-userna
me immeraufdemhund@yahoo.com --source-password *************
svnsync: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-re
vprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svnsync: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svnsync: E175002: Error setting property 'sync-lock':
Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook

Comment: ok so i'm such an idiot. I was committing that file to a folder called hooks instaed of logging in on the server and putting that hook in. So i did it as you said, but it is only grabbing version properties, do I have to do this over and over again?

Comment: I just have to add that one more step was needed. Svnsync sync. thank you very much mark for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Besides of `svnsync`, there is easier way of obtaining the dump of your repository: use [`svnrdump`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnrdump/) tool which was introduced in [Apache Subversion 1.7](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#svnrdump) release.